# How do I add sections to list and have section scroll on the side

Tags: swiftui, swift-playground

I’m a noob at this and need help. I’m trying to have my list alphabetically organized and have it divided into sections by letter. Also I want the user to have an option to have section scroller on the side. Pretty much I want it to look and work as contacts app. Is there an easy way to code it into my app?

Also my app is going to be in Russian

```
struct ContentView: View {
var psalms: [Psalm] = PsalmData.topTen
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List (psalms, id: \.id){ psalm in
                NavigationLink(destination: PsalmDetail(psalm: psalm)) {
                    Text(psalm.title)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                }
                .navigationTitle(Text("Оглавление"))
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
struct Psalm: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let title: String
let letter: String
let location: String
let object: String
```

struct PsalmData{

```
static let topTen = [
    Psalm(title: "А КОГДА ОН ПРИБЛИЗИЛСЯ",
          letter: "А",
          location: "Лук 19.37-40",
          object: "А когда Он приблизился к спуску с горы Елеонской, все множество учеников начало в радости велегласно славить Бога за все чудеса, какие видели они, говоря: благословен Царь, грядущий во имя Господне мир на небесах и слава в вышних! И некоторые фарисеи из среды народа сказали Ему: Учитель! Запрети ученикам Твоим. Но Он сказал им в ответ: сказываю вам, что если они умолкнут то камни возопиют."),
    Psalm(title: "БЛАЖЕН МУЖ",
          letter: "Б",
          location: "Пс.1",
          object: "Блажен муж, который не ходит на совет нечестивых и не стоит на пути грешных и не сидит в собрании развратителей, но в законе Господа воля его, и о законе Его размышляет он день и ночь! И будет он как дерево, посаженное при потоках вод, которое приносит плод свой во время свое, и лист которого не вянет; и во всем, что он ни делает, успеет. Не так - нечестивые; но они - как прах, возметаемый ветром с лица земли. Потому не устоят нечестивые на суде, и грешники – в собрании праведных. Ибо знает Господь путь праведных, а путь нечестивых погибнет."),
    Psalm(title: "БОЖЕ МОЙ! БОЖЕ МОЙ!",
          letter: "Б",
          location: "Пс.21.2-5",
          object: "Боже мой! Боже мой! для чего Ты оставил меня? Далеки от спасения моего слова вопля моего. Боже мой! я вопию днем, - и Ты не внемлешь мне, ночью, — и нет мне успокоения. Но Ты, Святый, живешь среди славословий Израиля. На Тебя уповали отцы наши; уповали, и Ты избавлял их."),
]
```

Btw I’m doing this on iPad with swift playgrounds

Comment: you want to have sections in your `List`, but I don't see any `Section` in your code. Have you look at using `Section`, like described here:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list
  or here: 
 https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-sections-to-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use a grouped list with alphabetical dictionaries. [Alphabetically sectioned list](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-section-lists-alphabetically-in-swiftui-e841f35993f)

To get a scroll bar you can wrap the List in a ScrollViewReader. Then add an id (.id(_ id: Hashable) on each section. With this, you’re able to scroll to the sections.

```
scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(_ id :Hashable)
```

Combine this with sectioning with the dictionary:

```
struct AlphabeticalList: View {
var abc: [String] = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p",]

var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader { scrollViewProxy in
        List {
            ForEach(abc, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(section) {
                    Text(section)
                }
                .id(section)
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(abc, id: \.self) { section in
                    Button(section) {
                        scrollViewProxy.scrollTo(section, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```